# Python threads stuck

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to switch from one thread called ***CameraProcessing*** to another thread called ***ServerKeypoints*** and viceversa.
To be precise, ***CameraProcessing*** changes a global variable called ***VALUE*** while ***ServerKeypoints*** consumes the global value by sending it via websocket to a client. To protect the global variable I've used the **Condition mechanism**.

I have two problems:

1. At a certain moment the script stucks, the threads don't go forward
2. The websocket client doesn't receive the data sent via websocket

The two threads are located in a script called **main_server.py** (I know that it is not the best idea and that it would be better to split these threads in different files).

**main_server.py**

```py
import threading
import asyncio
import websockets
condition = threading.Condition()
VALUE = 0
FLAG = 0


class ServerKeypoints(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    async def communicate(self, websocket):
        global VALUE
        global FLAG

        while True:
            condition.acquire()
            if FLAG == 1:
                FLAG = 0
                print(f"SERVER VAL: {VALUE}")
                await websocket.send(f"{VALUE}")
                condition.notify_all()
            else:
                condition.wait()
            condition.release()

    async def main(self,):
        async with websockets.serve(self.communicate, "localhost", 9998):
            await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.main())



class CameraProcessing(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    
    def run(self):
        global VALUE
        global FLAG

        while True:
            condition.acquire()
            if FLAG == 0:
                VALUE += 1
                print(f"CAMERA VAL: {VALUE}")
                FLAG = 1
                condition.notify_all()
            else:
                condition.wait()
            condition.release()
```

While **client.py** is written in the following way:

```py
import websocket

def on_message(wsapp, message):
    message = message
    print(message)

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:9998", on_message=on_message)
while True:
    wsapp.run_forever()
```

In the Visual Studio Code terminal I have a result like this:

```
CAMERA VAL: 20301
SERVER VAL: 20301
CAMERA VAL: 20302
SERVER VAL: 20302
CAMERA VAL: 20303
SERVER VAL: 20303
CAMERA VAL: 20304
SERVER VAL: 20304
CAMERA VAL: 20305
SERVER VAL: 20305
CAMERA VAL: 20306
SERVER VAL: 20306
CAMERA VAL: 20307
SERVER VAL: 20307
CAMERA VAL: 20308
SERVER VAL: 20308
CAMERA VAL: 20309
SERVER VAL: 20309
CAMERA VAL: 20310
SERVER VAL: 20310
CAMERA VAL: 20311
SERVER VAL: 20311
CAMERA VAL: 20312
SERVER VAL: 20312
CAMERA VAL: 20313
SERVER VAL: 20313
```

But it does not go forward.

Comment: If you run it multiple times, does it always stop at the same "VALUE"?

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the `async` stuff, but I've got to ask this:  You appear to be using `condition` and `FLAG` to ensure that the two loops never do anything concurrently. If that's the case, then what is the point of using threads or `async`? Threads and (as far as I know) `async` exist for no other purpose except to enable concurrent execution of your code.

Comment: Why do you use different libraries for client and server although "websockets" provides both functionality? You should at least begin with a single library to rule out some possible causes of problems.

Comment: @MichaelButscher not always but often it stops at the same value. And I tried to use "websockets" for the client, but it doesn't receive anything without any reason.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've used the async keyword because I copied it from the tutorials of the library. I've tried to work without async but it gives me exceptions and I'm not sure that it can work without async.

Comment: OK, maybe you can only call the `websockets` API from within a coroutine (i.e., an `async def`). I don't know; I'm still learning about that. But my point is more about the threads. You don't allow either thread to do anything interesting concurrently with any interesting thing that the other thread is doing. If you don't want anything to happen concurrently with anything else, then there is literally no reason to use threads..

Comment: @SolomonSlow I agree with you, I've used threads only for global variable protection but I don't know how to lock these variables.

Comment: Re, "used threads...for global variable protection" Sorry, I don't understand what that means. I will not be able to answer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've used threads because they share the global variable VALUE and in order to protect it I use thread locks like Condition

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Michal Butscher in the comments, I've tried again the client script provided by the ***websockets*** module and I've modified in the following way:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:9998", ping_interval=None) as websocket:
                msg = await websocket.recv()
                print(f"{msg}")
        except:
            continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(receive())
```

Now it doesn't stuck.

I know that the combination *async* and *thread* is not a good idea but if you have alternatives to propose I will be glad to read them.

Answer (score 0):

> I've used threads because they share the global variable VALUE and in order to protect it I use thread locks like Condition.

OK, but you don't need to create threads in order to use global variables. Your `ServerKeypoints` thread and your `CameraProcessing` thread never do any interesting thing concurrently with each other, so why not just have *one* thread that does this?

```python
async def communicate(self, websocket):
    global VALUE

    while True:
        VALUE += 1
        print(f"CAMERA VAL: {VALUE}")
        print(f"SERVER VAL: {VALUE}")
        await websocket.send(f"{VALUE}")
```

Get rid of the `condition`, get rid of the `FLAG`, get rid of the threads. It's a whole lot simpler, and (I'm pretty sure) it will do the same as what your example code does.